# After logging into google using gmail account when I google for any anything browser content is displaying in Hindi language intead of English

Tags: google-chrome

Steps to reproduce:
1)I logged in into  google chrome browser using my gmail account
2)If I am type anything then click on search button then browser content is displaying in Hindi language

Tried the below approach to resolve this issue but still facing the same problem:
1)Navigated to chrome Advanced settings and changed the language to English then cleared the browser cache and logged in again into the browser but still facing the issue.

Could you please help me on this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your language in Google [search settings](https://www.google.com/preferences#languages).

That will gonna change your language for Google Products.

If you still get Hindi Language, please let me know and I'll try my best to help you.

Comment: You're welcome, please tick my answer as worked so, people can know what answer is worked and what's not. You can see the tick mark below the votings buttons.

Comment: I think you're newer to Stack Overflow, the arrow buttons left side of answers below the arrow buttons, you can see a tick mark. Click that so, I'll get reputation and my answer will be marked as Answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to go to google account settings and pick the language or go to google.com then scroll down and you will find swtich to language.